# Can I print alternate elements of a list in Racket?

Tags: function, recursion, racket

For example, if I create a function named `odd-places`, it should work as follows,

```
(odd-places '(p q r s t 1 2)) = (p r t 2)
```

Can this be done using recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little addendum: With this function you can choose how many items in the list should be skipped before one gets included in the resulting list again.

```
(define (nth-places n lst [i 0])
  (cond
    [(null? lst) null]
    [(= i 0) (cons (car lst)
                   (nth-places n (cdr lst) (+ i 1)))]
    [(= i n) (nth-places n (cdr lst) 0)]
    [else (nth-places n (cdr lst) (+ i 1))]))
```

The `i` in `[i 0]` is an optional argument which you don't have to specify when you call the function, because it has the set start value 0 in this case. Here `i` functions as an accumulator index with which we start counting from zero instead of one.

The `n` defines that only all nth elements should be picked to construct the new list, again we start indexing at 0.

If you want to produce the alternating elements like here

```
(odd-places  '(p q r s t 1 2)) =  (p r t 2)
```

you would call

```
(nth-places 1 '(p q r s t 1 2))
```

For every third element set n to 2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The basic list tail recursion pattern in Scheme-like languages is :

- Check for stop condition, *here a `null?` test to stop recursion*
- Do the rest, *in this case add a branch to the conditional to filter odd indexes, hence `i` must be even (as it starts from 1 instead of 0)*

Applying this gives us

```
(define (odd-places lst)
  (define (remove-rec lst i)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          ((odd? i) (cons (car lst) (remove-rec (cdr lst) (+ i 1))))
          (else (remove-rec (cdr lst) (+ i 1))))) // i is even, skip this element!
  (remove-rec lst 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive approach where the task is solved with the use of two *mutually* recursive functions. In this approach there is no need of an auxiliary variable, checked for oddness or evenness.

```
(define (odd-places lst)
  (define (get lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (cons (car lst) (dont-get (cdr lst)))))
  (define (dont-get lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (get (cdr lst))))
  (get lst))
```

The first function `get` the first item from the list and cons it on the result of the second function applied to the rest of the list, which `dont-get` the first element of the list and returns immediately  the first function applied to the rest of the list.

This version is more efficient than the classical recursion in the answer of HyperZ in both space used on the stack and time of execution.

And finally, considering how the previous solution works, we can solve the problem “folding” the two inner functions in a single recursive call, without the need of auxiliary functions or variables:

```
(define (odd-places lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((null? (cdr lst)) (list (car lst)))
        (else (cons (car lst) (odd-places (cddr lst))))))
```

Comment: `(list (car lst))` can be simplified to just `lst` if the list has only one element as is the case here.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but re-creating the list we are guaranteed that no modification to the original list will affect the result of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is actually showing the *even* elements of your list, since the zeroth (even) element is `p`. So that’s why the solution below uses `even?`.

Other answers have featured instructive recursive solutions, but you haven’t stated why you need it to be recursive. In case you just want a concise way to get alternates, a “comprehension” also works:

```
(for/list ([i (length lst)] #:when (even? i))
  (list-ref lst i))
```

[More info on `for/list` here.](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29)

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version than the previous answers:

```scm
(define (odd-places lst)
  (if (or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst)))
          lst
          (cons (car lst) (odd-places (cddr lst)))))
```

Testing:

```scm
> (odd-places  '(p q r s t 1 2))
'(p r t 2)
```