# How to create a function that receives a list and creates a new list in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, mit-scheme

I'm trying to create a function called `evenElememt` that takes a list as a parameter and appends all the elements in even positions to a new list and displays the new list.

My attempt:

```lisp
(define newList '())

(define elementHelper
  (lambda lst
      ((cdr lst)
      (cons newList (car lst))
      (elementHelper(cdr lst)))
  )
)

(define evenElement
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond
      ((null? lst) ())
      ((null? (cdr lst)) ())
      (else (elementHelper lst)
            (display lst))
    )
  )
)
```

Example output: if I enter `(evenElement '('a 'b 'c 'f 't 'y))`, the output should be `(b f y)`.

Comment: What is `elementList`?

Comment: You shouldn't use quotes inside a quoted list.

Comment: elementList is the list, i'll fix that thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially the same as [Can I print alternate elements of a list in Racket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575637/can-i-print-alternate-elements-of-a-list-in-racket), except that you want to print even positions (1-indexed) instead of odd positions.

```lisp
(define (even-positions lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         '())
        ((null? (cdr lst))
         '())
        (else
          (cons (second lst)
                (even-positions (cddr lst))))))
```

`(even-positions '(a b c f t y))` returns `'(b f y)`.

Then, this is the function you are looking for:

```lisp
(define (display-even-positions lst)
  (display (even-positions lst)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `elementHelper`. Just make `evenElement` return the result instead of displaying it.

You also don't need the global variable `newList`. The function should construct the result as it goes.

```
(define evenElement
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond
     ((null? lst) '())
     ((null? (cdr lst)) '())
     (else (cons (car (cdr lst)) 
           (evenElement (cdr (cdr lst)))))
     )
    )
  )

(display (evenElement '(a b c f t y)))
```